# Difference between questions about array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, hash

What is the difference between

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

and

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-with-given-sum/

I understand the answers are different but the question is the same, is not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question is asking you **if** there are two numbers that match the sum. (Return a boolean)

The other is asking you **how many** two numbers match the sum. (Return a number)

Comment: So the implementation should be the same. The only difference should be in the return. Am I wrong?

Comment: What I mean is that in this both questions we have implementations totally different when the question is almost te same

Comment: You can have the same implementation on both functions. The thing is, you can be more efficient on the if question because you stop earlier. So maybe your question should be, why is the "if " question implementation more efficient then the "how many" implementation.